# Python kernel died when using tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am using tensorflow (CPU version only) under python 3.5.2 within anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit) in Windows 7 Operation System. When I run the following code, the python kernel died and could not restart with some errors but no error information prompt.

```
print ("test accuracy %.3f" % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={  
    x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

But when I run the similar codes, python works normally:

```
train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={  
    x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
```

Which reason could cause this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that `mnist` actually holds, but looks like you are pushing the whole test set for evaluation, which is 10 000 images. Even for a medium size neural network it's a lot. The process is likely to die with OOM.

Try to pass a smaller batch, say of size 100.